# Using country-select with formastic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, country-codes

I am trying to use country-select with formastic as:

```
:country_of_residence, :as => :country
```

problem is that i want to put New Zealand on the top not other countries. 
How can I do that within formastic???

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<%= f.input :nationality, :as => :country, :priority_countries => ["New Zealand"] %>
```